# PowerBI Row Totals for only one Column

Tags: powerbi

Trying to show only the row totals for one column, not every nested row within. I only need TaskCostCenter, not TaskName or EmployeeName. This is for the Matrix table.

[image]

[image]

I've adjusted Row Subtotals to what I thought would only be for a specific row, but if I uncheck Per Row Level or Show Subtotal, I lost the TaskCostCenter totals.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution when digging around. I went into Row Subtotals, then for the rows I did not want totals for, I set the Show Subtotal to OFF. I did this for each one EXCEPT for the one I wanted, and everything cleared right up.

[image]

[image]